# Booting Windows 10 from USB and weird partition issues

Tags: windows-10, command-line, partitioning, bsod, bootable-media

So some quick background. I have an HP Spectre x360 that is just over a year old and until now, has been working fine. Two nights ago, I used the computer and everything was fine. I went to sleep, and when I opened my laptop less than 6 hours later, I got a blue screen of death saying there were errors that needed to be fixed. I tried the auto-repair tool and restarting but the BSOD was in a cyclical loop and Windows wouldn't boot up. It said it was an "NTFS_File_Error" stop code. The only things recently installed on the inbuilt SSD was a music-making program and a game. The computer functioned fine for at least a week after both those installations. I took it to Best Buy, the guy told me my drives were healthy but it looked like I just needed to do a clean install of Windows 10 from a USB because it was a booting error.

So I came home, got my Windows 10 bootable USB, and tried to install it using the steps in this article https://www.groovypost.com/howto/clean-install-Windows-10/. I deleted out the existing partitions and went through the install process but after it went through the "Windows Setup" process, it said the installation was unsuccessful and couldn't be written to the disk. It went to the BSOD again and this time I opened command prompt from the repair options to check what happened to the disks and partitions using DISKPART. This is the output I got:

> ```
>   Diskpart> list partition
>
>   Partition ###  Type        Size     Offset
>   -------------  ----------  -------  --------
>   Partition 1    System      100 MB   1024 KB
>   Partition 2    Reserved    16 MB    101 MB
>   Partition 3    System      100 MB   117 MB
> * Partition 7    Primary     237 GB   477 MB
> ```

What happened to partitions 4-6??? All I did was delete the existing partitions and then I thought I created a system and primary to install Windows 10 to, but clearly that was not the case. I also checked the volumes I had as follows:

> ```
> Diskpart> list volume
>
> Volume ###  Ltr  Label      Fs     Type       Size     Status    Info
> ----------  ---  ---------  -----  ---------  -------  --------  -------
> Volume 0     H              NTFS   Partition  237 GB   Healthy   Pagefile
> Volume 1     C              FAT32  Partition  100 MB   Healthy   Hidden
> Volume 3     E              FAT32  Partition  100 MB   Healthy   Hidden
> ```

So now I am not sure what to do. Before I ran the windows installer from the USB, there were labels on the volumes and the partitions were 1-4 (i.e. there wasn't skipped numbers). My understanding of this stuff is rather poor so I'd appreciate any help I can get! I am probably going to go back to Best Buy and just pay them the several hundred bucks to fix it if I can't but I thought I would see if anyone else had suggestions before I bite that bullet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MBR or GPT ? Did you delete all partitions before fresh install ??

Comment: GPT. I definitely thought I did because I was left only with one partition of unallocated space and one partition of reserved (because they said to only delete the system and primary partitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A little explanation -*

In MBR disks primary **partitions can have gaps** in their numbering. They work sort of like Post Office boxes; the numbers don't change when one goes vacant. The **same is true of the newer GPT partitions** . Logical partitions, though, take on contiguous numbers starting with 5, so you won't normally see gaps in logical partition numbers.
So in your case those missing partition numbers are kind of justifiable.{we can think what installer did - first created the new partition {partition 7} and then tried to delete the older ones{partition 4 5 6} and hence the number}

---

What can you do !!??

Delete all the partitions ***one by one using diskpart*** or simply ***clean the drive*** using diskpart.After that carry on with your installation normally !!

**To Delete all the partitions one by one**

```
List part: Display partitions available on the drive (a fabric state would not have partitions)
Sel part: Used to select a partition to work on
Del part: Used to delete the selected partition
```

**To simply clean the drive**

```
List disk: Displays the list of attached disks and USB flash drives
Sel disk (select disk): Selects the scope to work in
Clean all: Removes partition and volume information from the selected device
```

---

From comment section :

> because they said to only delete the system and primary partitions

Windows will create the required partitions itself during install. No need to keep recovery partitions.It may confuse the installer as in your case !!

Comment: Thanks so much! This really helped!

Comment: Why did you suggest clean all? Writing 0 to whole disk can take a rather long time, in this case, to erase partition table, a simple clean will do.